# Замедление скрипта при смене вкладки браузера

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь написать таймер при помощи setInterval и при условии что пользователь находится постоянно на "нашей" вкладке - всё предельно понятно. Но при смене вкладки браузера, JS слегка замедляет работу setInterval. Можно ли этого как-то избежать?

```js
let test = setInterval( () => console.log(performance.now()), 1000);

document.querySelector('#start').onclick = () => {
  test = setInterval( () => console.log(performance.now()), 1000);
};
document.querySelector('#stop').onclick = () => clearInterval(test);
```

```html
<button id = 'start'> start </button>
<button id = 'stop'> stop </button>
```

Comment: хром и фаерфокс так специально делают. Можете в сторону вебворкеров глянуть, если это вам подойдет

Comment: на счет остальных браузеров не уверен

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs